# React Counting Words in a TextArea PROBLEM

Tags: reactjs, textarea

This is the edited code.

```
    <textarea
      className= "textarea"
      placeholder="write the description here"
      value={this.state.input} 
      onChange={(ev) => {
        this.updateBody(ev.target.value)
        }
      }>
    </textarea>
```

And then I call the functions in order to save the data to Firebase.

```
 updateBody = async (val) => {
    await this.setState({ input: val });
    await this.setState({ wordsCounted :val.split(' ').length });
    await this.setState({charactersCounted : val.length })
    /*assign the number of words inside the textarea to the variable wordsCounted*/
    this.update();
  };
  updateTitle = async (txt) => {
    await this.setState({ title: txt });
    this.update();
  }
  update = debounce(() => {
    this.props.noteUpdate(this.state.id, {
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.input,
      /*Send the value of the var wordsCounted to Firebase*/
      wordsCounted : this.state.wordsCounted,
      charactersCounted : this.state.charactersCounted

    })
  }, 750);
```

The problem is that I don't know why `title` and `body` are being saved while `wordsCounted` and `charactersCounted` not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the onChange event's event object. If you set the state for the length of the text in the textarea within the onChange event, you can obtain the count of characters. If you use Zunayed Shahriar's suggestion to count words, then the state will store the count of words. However, there is one bug here to fix: The space character is counted as a word. Thus, when "hello" is one word, "hello " is two words. "hello world" is also counted two words.

Here is the code I suggest. Note that I use the value state to make textarea a controlled input.

```js
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: '', length: 0 }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.length)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => {
          this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
          this.setState({ length: e.target.value.split(' ').length })
        }}></textarea>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

As reference to the accepted answer, use

```
this.setState({ length: e.target.value.trim().split(' ').length })
```

to get correct word count, as blank spaces at end counts as a word.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Typo.

It is `this.state.input.length` not `this.state.input.lenght`.

And it won't count words. It'll count characters.

So, you'll have to use `this.state.input.split(' ').length` to get words count.

And if still there are errors, then add the component to the question.

Comment: Now it works. But there is another problem left: 'wordsCounted' and 'charactersCounted' are not being saved in Firebase.. I edited the code so you can see it

Comment: Can you upload the react project or create a minimal reproduction at CodeSandbox or StackBlitz?

Comment: I found the Solution!